# Telerik MVC New Project Template

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

When i want to use Visual Studio to open new Telerik MVC project, everything is OK but, it is not Bootstrap3. It shows, old design of ASP.net projects. 
Should i need to configure anything ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the latest Visual Studio template.
Check here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/vs-integration/introduction